# Android - Start Activities From Service

Tags: android, service

I have been reading about services and how to use them, but I need some advice.

Currently I have an app which has a MainActivity with a setContentView which sets up the main menu. And there are some buttons which then start other activities.

So you have MainActivity -> Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity C

And after going through the app I have it so onBackPress finish() is called and you can go back to the main menu.

From what I understand an Android application must run an activity on launch?

So if I am to implement a service, I have to start an activity and then run a service from that activity.

I want my app to use a service so it isn't a background/cached process when the user clicks the Home button.

So how should I approach this?

I was thinking that I could have an activity that has a sole purpose of creating a Service, and then I could have that service launch the MainActivity?

If that is how I should go about it, once the user navigates back to the Main Activity, will executing finish() exit the app? I would think not .. so how would I kill the service that begun the Main Activity?

Comment: Can you tell me a little more about what you are trying to accomplish with the service? Is it to consume web services and transfer some data via JSON?

Comment: It just plays mp3's the app that is. I want it as a service, so it is visible when they click the home button in the running apps. Otherwise they have to show the cached/background processes to exit it.